# What does shading indicate in home range plot?

Tags: r, spatial-statistics

I've simulated a home range in R using the clusthr function from the adehabitatHR package. The home range is made from 50 x,y coordinates. The output is attached.

[image]

I'm trying to get clear on what the shading indicates. The shading is clearly related to the size of the polygon. Smaller polygons = darker shading, larger polygons = paler shading. But how exactly is a polygon assigned a shade? Does the shading represent a percentage of the area covered?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

This does not seem to be documented in the `clusthr` manual page, but because the source code is available, we can try to figure it out.

By typing

```
> clusthr
```

at the `R` prompt (shown as the initial `>`), you can see the code.  It's opaque, but a quick look indicates (1) there's no plotting or color selection going on and (2) the clustering is performed with a call to a C function.  There's no plotting because this code only produces an object that will be plotted later with `plot`.

The version of `plot` to use is determined by the class of the object returned by `clusthr`: the docs say this is a class named "MCHu".  Therefore we inspect the code of its corresponding plotting function by typing

```
> plot.MCHu
```

Here is a key part of the output:

```
...
co <- grey(c(1:nrow(df))/nrow(df))
plot(x, col = co, ...)
...
```

Evidently the colors are graduated from dark to light in even increments and assigned to polygons in the order they are found in the `MCHu` object.  At this point we do some reverse-engineering by generating such an object using the example from the `clusthr` manual page:

```
> data(puechabonsp)
> lo<-puechabonsp$relocs[,1]
> res <- clusthr(lo)
```

A request `str(res)` to inspect the structure of `res` is met with a huge amount of output, which is therefore almost worthless, but it's evident this is a list, so let's try to inspect the structure of just its first element:

```
> str(res[[1]])
```

This time the output is manageable (although still ridiculously long for such a small amount of information).  It begins

```
Formal class 'SpatialPolygonsDataFrame' [package "sp"] with 5 slots
  ..@ data       :'data.frame': 22 obs. of  2 variables:
  .. ..$ percent: num [1:22] 10 13.3 23.3 26.7 36.7 ...
  .. ..$ area   : num [1:22] 0.0179 0.0457 0.0664 0.0947 0.2717 ...
  ..@ polygons   :List of 22
```

OK, the polygons are what we're interested in, so let's inspect *their* structure, but this time we will be a little cautious.  Since they are a list, let's inspect just the first one:

```
> res[[1]]@polygons[[1]]

An object of class "Polygons"
Slot "Polygons":
[[1]]
An object of class "Polygon"
Slot "labpt":
[1]  698994.7 3161001.7

Slot "area":
[1] 179
...
```

OK--in the `area` slot there is something interesting related to the hypothesis that shading corresponds to polygon size.  (There are actually *two* `area` slots in this object: probably somebody extended a class that includes an `area` slot but they inadvertently added another; only one of them will be accessible through the `@area` construct.)  Let's print out those areas, in order:

```
> sapply(1:length(res[[1]]@polygons), function(i) res[[1]]@polygons[[i]]@area)

 [1]    179.0    456.5    663.5    947.0   2717.0   7928.5   9761.5  12790.5
 [9]  14839.0  16404.0  18100.0  18325.0  23731.5  37658.5  58793.0  70735.5
[17]  82063.0 105812.5 182443.0 226467.0 252571.5 405963.5
```

The polygons appear to be sorted by increasing area.  This is true for the other three components of `res` (as we may find by repeating the preceding command, replacing `res[[1]]` by `res[[2]]`, etc.)  Assuming it is always the case that `clusthr` orders the polygons by increasing area, we may tentatively conclude that *lightness corresponds to the **ranks** of the polygon areas,* with lighter polygons having larger area.

Comment: Such a great breakdown of how to debug in R. Insightful!